# How To Aggregate Up From A Text Table With Calculated Fields?

Tags: tableau-api

With tableau I am able to act on some data tables to get to a text table that I would like to treat as a table from scratch to do further aggregation. You will see from my example what I actually want to do, but acting on a text table as if it were a brand new table seems to be one solution if possible. I am open to other solutions to the same problem if you have any.

Say I have two tables.

**Table A**

Date | Purchases

'2014-05-02' | 5

'2014-05-03' | 6

**Table B**

Date Bucket | Bake Rate

0-1 Month | .20

2-3 Month | .50

First I created a calculated field for Table A to put each line item date into the corresponding date bucket by figuring out how much time has passed from a certain date and called it Date Bucket. Then I made a relationship between Date Bucket in Table B and the newly formed dimension in Table A also called Date Bucket. From Here I could essentially join on date bucket and for each line item get a Bake Rate from table B.

Then I divide each purchase by the corresponding bake rate as determined by how Age Bucket.

So I ended up with a text table like the following.

Date | Age Bucket | Purchases | Baked Purchases

'2014-05-02' | 0-1 Month | 5 | 25

'2014-05-03' | 0-1 Month | 6 | 30

Ideally, from here I'd like to be able to get the sum of the baked purchases and aggregate by whatever other dimensions I have. For example here, get the sum of baked purchases by month.

Any Ideas?!

Comment: you state that you have this new table with date, age bucket, purchases, baked purchases. Why can't you just drop those onto a visual? are you getting an error. Is this question more concerned with using the new table as a reference to a more high dimensional table? If so you are probably looking for a data blending solution

Comment: I'm saying that once I get the new resultant table in Tableau with Date | Age Bucket | Purchases | Baked Purchases, I'd like to roll that table up. IE I would want to aggregate and get 

Month | Purchases | Baked Purchases


Date | Purchases | Baked Purchases

May | 11 | 55

Comment: You can simply drop the date and age bucket ref into col or row shelf. then bring the purchases and baked purchases into the measures

Comment: I don't think that works.

http://imgur.com/3lFd97W

Here is a screenshot of where I am at. From here I'd like to aggregate to month. So for this example, Id want a table showing Month | Leads | Baked Lead Count|  May | 19 | 842

Comment: Won you could select the dimension in the shelf and choose month or year month. You could also nest the bucket in the date to give you an expandable functionality